# How to increase spin speed in velocity.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, velocity.js

I am using velocity.js for spinner and let user spin multiple times.
Currently my code spins the wheel for only few seconds but i want it to spin about more than a minute.
I couldn't find any solution for this so is there any solution?

```
$(".fancybox").parent("li").velocity({
    opacity: 1
}, {
    duration: 100,
    complete: function () {
        $(".wheel").velocity({
            rotateZ: "-" + _deg + "deg",
        },
        {
            duration: 1500,
            direction: 'clockwise',                     
            speed: 9000,
            easing: "swing",
            tween: [0, 100],                                                
            complete: function (elements) 
            {}
        });
    }
});
```

This is working [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/41bcmpa6/) i am attaching.

Comment: Change the 3000 to a bigger number?

Comment: The question title mentions "speen **speed**" but the question itself seems to be about the spin **duration**. Which is it?

Comment: @Pointy My mistake it's spin duration.. chaging 3000 doesn't work.